# How to scroll into child component in a list from parent in react?

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

Hello guys I have an issue that may be simple but I'm stuck.
I have a parent that call an endpoint and render a list of child components once the data is received, at the same time in the URL could (or not) exists a parameter with the same name as the "name" property of one of the child components, so if parameter exists I need to scroll the page down until the children component that have the same "name" as id.
Here is part of the code:

```
const ParentView = () => {
  const [wines, setWines] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

  const params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
  const isMx = params.get('lang') ? false : true;
  const wineId = params.get('wine');

  const ref = createRef();
  const scroll = () => ref && ref.current && ref.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    retrieveData();
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEmptyArray(wines) && !loading && wineId) scroll();
  }, [wineId, wines, loading]);


  function renderWines() {
    if (loading) return <Loading />;

    if (isEmptyArray(wines) && !loading) return <h2>No items found</h2>;

    if (!isEmptyArray(wines) && !loading)
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          {wines
            .filter(p => p.status === 'published')
            .map((w, idx) => (
              <ChildComponent
                wine={w}
                isMx={isMx}
                idx={idx}
                openModal={openModal}
                ref={wineId === w.name.toLowerCase() ? ref : null}
              />
            ))}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {renderWines()}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

And this is the child component...

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';
import { Row,} from 'reactstrap';

const WineRow = forwardRef(({ wine, isMx, idx, openModal }, ref) => {

  const {
    name,
  } = wine;

  // const ref = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // console.log({ ref, shouldScrollTo });
    // shouldScrollTo && ref.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Row id={name} ref={ref}>
      ...content that is irrelevant for this example
    </Row>
  );
});
```

Of course I remove a lot of irrelevant code like `retrieveData()` function and all the logic to handle the data from api
I've been trying many ways but I can't make it works :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a headache I just realized that I don't need react to do this 
so I just fixit with vanilla js ‍♂️

Parent:

```
const Public = () => {
  const [wines, setWines] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

  const params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
  const isMx = params.get('lang') ? false : true;
  const wineId = params.get('wine');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    retrieveData();
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEmptyArray(wines) && !loading && wineId) scroll(wineId);
  }, [wineId, wines, loading]);

  const scroll = wineId => document.getElementById(wineId).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });

  const retrieveData = async () => {
   ....logic to handle data
  };


  function renderWines() {
    if (loading) return <Loading />;

    if (isEmptyArray(wines) && !loading) return <h2>No items found</h2>;

    if (!isEmptyArray(wines) && !loading)
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          {wines
            .filter(p => p.status === 'published')
            .map((w, idx) => (
              <WineRow wine={w} isMx={isMx} idx={idx} />
            ))}

        </React.Fragment>
      );
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {renderWines()}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

and children:

```
const WineRow =({ wine, isMx, idx,}) => {

  const {
    name,
  } = wine;

  return (
    <Row id={name.toLowerCase()}>
      ...content that is irrelevant for this example
    </Row>
  );
};
```

And that's it  sometimes we are used to do complex things that we forgot our basis ‍♂️

Hope this help someone in the future